# What is the anatomy of a video file?

Tags: ffmpeg, editing, encoding, file-formats, recommendation

I am creating a software related to video editing.
So, I need to understand what is a video file, how is it created and how does it work?
One thing that I want to achieve is: I want to be able to add chapters to existing videos that can be used in vlc media players `Chapters` option in the **Playback** menu

This question may sound weird. But please consider that I am completely new to realm of `video construction/editing/creating` and I don't find any resource to start learning from
Any suggestion gratefully received. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Dron - welcome. You have a few questions in there, and they can all be answered in different ways, so can you please edit it down to one question. Before doing that, please read other questions on video file structure as we have quite a few here and they may answer your needs.

Comment: @DrMayhem Can you mention some resource to to start learning how videos work... the mechanism behind videos -- any resource on this topic... excluding Wikipedia

Comment: @DrMayhem I can understand that this question is a mess. As I said I am just a newbie to this topic. You can edit this question if you can understand my intention behind this question.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the common video files are containers (like *.mp4, *.mkv) - they can hold different type of streams (video, audio, subtitles, data) and some additional description of these streams (metadata). There are also some video files with a raw video data (like *.h264) - they are representing single video stream and they can also be used with some video players.
([more info about video files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_file_format))